# What is the best way for an amateur researcher to communicate with an academic?

Tags: research-process, etiquette, computer-science, independent-researcher

If a  amateur researcher believes that he  has a result (average result,not ground breaking result),   what  should he  do  to communicate  an academic (who is a stranger)?

How should one approach?

Comment: Why should he want to communicate to an academic?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano , to  discuss the idea , to verify , to see the possibility/prospect of that idea/paper

Comment: If you are a crank, then please just keep whatever you find to yourself. If you are an amateur researcher genuinely interested in feedback on your work, that is another matter entirely.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft , what is the difference? how do you distinguish?

Comment: The distinction is in the genuine interest in feedback (which of course includes accepting the possibility that the proposed result or its proof could be wrong).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft wrong, you don't need go that far. Academics are entitled to tag "crank"  whenever they like. For example, one may tag you "crank" if your paper title    has  upper case lower case  problem, without reading the paper.

Comment: Yeah, that attitude is going to make me want to engage further with you, sure. Have fun trying to get anyone to take you seriously.

Comment: Jim, do you understand that many academics probably have no interest in discussing and pursuing that idea or verify it, even if it's good? Most academics do not have a shortage of ideas, they lack the time to pursue them. Thus yours (or whoever's) idea, if not cranky, would simply fall in the category of ideas that might be good, together with some other ten or more ideas.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano yes I do understand that. That is why I am  asking how to convince them, and a paper is not just an idea, it has more to say.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear because the OP has been asked to clarify why the question is about a crank, and has not clarified the issue.

Comment: @BenCrowell , who asked  to clarify? anyway, I edited.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. I have no idea what OP is trying to communicate to an academic (and I shouldn't have to read through a lot of comments to figure it out, either).

Comment: RJLipton says: ".. it must pass the Elevator Pitch Test... you must be able to convince an expert that you have a new idea that gives you the 'edge' that no one previously had. The edge that makes it possible for you to have solved the problem." -- https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2009/02/16/proofs-and-elevator-rides/

Comment: @DanielR.Collins , that is  really helpful thanks. For example, Good examples would be: “I noticed that X is true and so I could prove the result if I could only show Y. For some reason no one before noticed that X was true.” An expert hearing this would say, “Cool, I never noticed that X is true. I can see why this gives you an edge.”.. understood.

Comment: From my experience (also in other fields such as art/music etc.) that amateurs asking professionals for help means that they want to have the cheap task of producing an idea and have the less rewarding heavy lifting done by the professionals for their (the amateur's) benefit. It does not work like that: for a professional to take an amateur seriously, it must be clear that they did much heavy lifting themselves. Respect needs to be earned, and that takes time, hard work and persistence. Absent that, a pithy elevator pitch is the next best thing to try.

Answer (score 9):

There are some general facts to consider here. First, researchers are always busy. This means you only have a few seconds to attract their attention. Second, they're usually knowledgeable in very specific areas of interest. This means, they will be more willing to consider your idea if they know its background already. The "crank" should consider these facts to improve her chances to attract the researcher's attention:

1. Choose a researcher who has investigated the specific problem addressed by the result before.
2. The initial e-mail should be brief as well as terse. 3-5 sentences. One sentence should state the problem. One sentence should intelligently summarize the researcher's previous work on the problem. One sentence should summarize the novel idea to solve the problem.
3. Any more detailed explanations should be attached to the e-mail in a readable and well-organized form, preferably as a PDF file.

Comment: Nice answer, +1, but you didn't read my 3 line post properly,   i have stated "average result,not ground breaking result".

Comment: Can you say which part of my answer would not apply in the case of an average result?

Comment: No, its ok.  I misread

Comment: Pro tip: Read more carefully and think before you write. An interaction like that would be an instant-cutoff by a busy academic.

Answer (score 6):

**Learn the language of the field**. If you speak with property of research matters, you have many more chances that people will take you seriously. If you seem unaware of even the basic results and notation, your e-mail is very likely going to end in the trash.

To learn the language, you will have to **study** a lot: follow undergraduate- and then graduate-level courses. You are not ready to tackle a research problem until you know what people before you have done, at least to the level to which a university student does it. You need to know which theorems are already known and which results are new / interesting / open problems.